# Very bad wifi connection, XPS 13 9350 Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, dell, broadcom

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on the new XPS 13 9350 Laptop by Dell, it comes with a broadcom chip that isn't supported out of the box.

I'm getting 1.5 Megabit download speed, if I tether to my phone that’s connected to the same network I get 20.

What I've done:

Wiped windows

installed ubuntu 15.10

dist-upgrade, upgrade

updated to bios 1.0.5

installed kernel 4.4 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

installed GUC from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/sklgucver43

Ran:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'i915 nvme' >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules"
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Rebooted

WiFi didn't work

Downloaded http://en.community.dell.com/cfs-fil..._2D00_pcie.zip

unzipped

ran

```
sudo mv brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin /lib/firmware/brcm
sudo chmod 600 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
```

rebooted

WiFi works but very very slow and often drops, any ideas?

journalctl:

```
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmf_fil_cmd_data: bus is down. we have nothing to do.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: Trying to free nonexistent resource <000000000000e000-000000000000e0ff>
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: suspend of devices complete after 132.319 msecs
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: late suspend of devices complete after 19.542 msecs
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 31.959 msecs
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: ACPI : EC: EC stopped
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: ACPI: Low-level resume complete
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: ACPI : EC: EC started
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel:  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: CPU1 is up
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel:  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: CPU2 is up
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel:  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: CPU3 is up
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 17.064 msecs
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: early resume of devices complete after 7.695 msecs
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: usb 1-4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [drm] RC6 on
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: resume of devices complete after 1631.128 msecs
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: PM: Finishing wakeup.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 110
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: done.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.txt failed with error -2
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd-logind[653]: Lid opened.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1265]: Time has been changed
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4350C5
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (003.006.007) build 0000
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd failed with error -2
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6412.hcd not found
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 avahi-daemon[648]: Withdrawing workstation service for wlp58s0.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Time has been changed
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[8849]: [18066:18320:0117/204609:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(248)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 dbus[607]: [system] Rejected send message, 10 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.84" (uid=1000 pid=1686 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.25" (uid=0 pid=814 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 dbus[607]: [system] Rejected send message, 10 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.84" (uid=1000 pid=1686 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.25" (uid=0 pid=814 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 dbus[607]: [system] Rejected send message, 10 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.84" (uid=1000 pid=1686 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.25" (uid=0 pid=814 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 dbus[607]: [system] Rejected send message, 10 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.84" (uid=1000 pid=1686 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.25" (uid=0 pid=814 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <warn>  (wlp58s0): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 gnome-session[9002]: (deja-dup-monitor:10118): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 775 was not found when attempting to remove it
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Not enough free handles to register service
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd-udevd[19288]: Process '/bin/hciconfig hci0 up' failed with exit code 1.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Error adding Link Loss service
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd-sleep[19272]: System resumed.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Not enough free handles to register service
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill3...
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Not enough free handles to register service
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Not enough free handles to register service
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: sleep.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Current Time Service could not be registered
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: gatt-time-server: Input/output error (5)
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Not enough free handles to register service
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Not enough free handles to register service
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Sap driver initialization failed.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:3a:00.0/net/wlp58s0, iface: wlp58s0)
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  radio killswitch /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:3a:00.0/ieee80211/phy1/rfkill3 disappeared
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 ModemManager[660]: <info>  (net/wlp58s0): released by modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:3a:00.0
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 bluetoothd[814]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.84 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill4...
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Stopping Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill2...
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd-logind[653]: Operation finished.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: suspend.target: Unit is bound to inactive unit systemd-suspend.service. Stopping, too.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  waking up...
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs at resume.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill3.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Stopped Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill2.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill4.
jan 17 20:46:09 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: [drm:intel_dp_link_training_channel_equalization [i915]] *ERROR* 5.4 Gbps link rate without HBR2/TPS3 support
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Oct 22 2015 06:16:26 version 7.35.180.119 (r594535) FWID 01-e791c176
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  rfkill5: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:3a:00.0/ieee80211/phy2/rfkill5) (driver brcmfmac)
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlan0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill5...
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlan0): new 802.11 WiFi device (carrier: UNKNOWN, driver: 'brcmfmac', ifindex: 16)
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill5.
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  keyfile: add connection in-memory (84a96104-054c-4e9b-96c9-53bd01db1a24,"MotoG3 Network")
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  BT device MotoG3 (40:88:05:BD:F3:99) added (NAP)
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (40:88:05:BD:F3:99): new Bluetooth device (carrier: UNKNOWN, driver: 'bluez', ifindex: 0)
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (40:88:05:BD:F3:99): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 org.freedesktop.Notifications[8849]: le'loading icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-low' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-low' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-off' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-off' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-low' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-low' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-off' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-off' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-low' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-notification-display-brightness-low' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-nm-no-connection' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-nm-no-connection' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-nm-device-wireless' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-nm-device-wireless' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-notification-network-wireless-disconnected' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-notification-network-wireless-disconnected' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-nm-device-wireless' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-nm-device-wireless' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-notification-network-wireless-disconnected' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-notification-network-wireless-disconnected' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-nm-no-connection' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-nm-no-connection' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-nm-device-wireless' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-nm-device-wireless' not present in theme Numix-Circle'loading icon 'notification-notification-network-wireless-disconnected' caused error: 'Icon 'notification-notification-network-wireless-disconnected' not present in the
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:3a:00.0/net/wlp58s0, iface: wlp58s0)
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:3a:00.0/net/wlp58s0, iface: wlp58s0): no ifupdown configuration found.
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlan0): interface index 16 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlp58s0'
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlp58s0 already exists
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (40:88:05:BD:F3:99): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Device '40:88:05:BD:F3:99' has no connection; scheduling activate_check in 0 seconds.
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlp58s0 already exists
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp58s0 flags: No such device
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Device 'wlp58s0' has no connection; scheduling activate_check in 0 seconds.
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp58s0: link is not ready
jan 17 20:46:10 david-XPS-13-9350 gnome-session[9002]: (nm-applet:9142): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 15338 was not found when attempting to remove it
jan 17 20:46:12 david-XPS-13-9350 ModemManager[660]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:3a:00.0': not supported by any plugin
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: p2p-dev-wlp58s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Auto-activating connection 'VGV75196892AB'.
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): Activation: starting connection 'VGV75196892AB' (d496e759-7d2b-41a8-89da-7805fed345c6)
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'VGV75196892AB' has security, but secrets are required.
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'VGV75196892AB' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Config: added 'ssid' value 'VGV75196892AB'
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: wlp58s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'VGV75196892AB'
jan 17 20:46:13 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
jan 17 20:46:14 david-XPS-13-9350 com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[8849]: [18066:18320:0117/204614:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(248)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
jan 17 20:46:14 david-XPS-13-9350 compiz[9351]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: wlp58s0: Associated with 4c:09:d4:68:92:ab
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp58s0: link becomes ready
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: wlp58s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 4c:09:d4:68:92:ab [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: wlp58s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 4c:09:d4:68:92:ab completed [id=0 id_str=]
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 wpa_supplicant[762]: p2p-dev-wlp58s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=NL
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: NL
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 kernel: cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'VGV75196892AB'.
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Activation (wlp58s0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  dhclient started with pid 19348
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 dhclient[19348]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.6 on wlp58s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x133526fe)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 dhclient[19348]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.6 from 192.168.2.254
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    address 192.168.2.6
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    gateway 192.168.2.254
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    server identifier 192.168.2.254
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    lease time 86400
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    nameserver '192.168.2.254'
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    nameserver '195.241.77.55'
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    nameserver '195.241.77.58'
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>    domain name 'home'
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): DHCPv4 state changed unknown -> bound
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 avahi-daemon[648]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp58s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.6.
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 avahi-daemon[648]: New relevant interface wlp58s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 avahi-daemon[648]: Registering new address record for 192.168.2.6 on wlp58s0.IPv4.
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 dhclient[19348]: bound to 192.168.2.6 -- renewal in 34830 seconds.
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 whoopsie[631]: [20:46:17] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 whoopsie[631]: [20:46:17] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[8849]: [18066:18320:0117/204617:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(248)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Policy set 'VGV75196892AB' (wlp58s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1040]: setting upstream servers from DBus
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1040]: using nameserver 192.168.2.254#53
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1040]: using nameserver 195.241.77.55#53
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 dnsmasq[1040]: using nameserver 195.241.77.58#53
jan 17 20:46:17 david-XPS-13-9350 dbus[607]: [system] Rejected send message, 10 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.58" (uid=0 pid=1040 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.10" (uid=0 pid=622 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
jan 17 20:46:19 david-XPS-13-9350 avahi-daemon[648]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp58s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3252:cbff:fee8:1d97.
jan 17 20:46:19 david-XPS-13-9350 avahi-daemon[648]: New relevant interface wlp58s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
jan 17 20:46:19 david-XPS-13-9350 avahi-daemon[648]: Registering new address record for fe80::3252:cbff:fee8:1d97 on wlp58s0.*.
jan 17 20:46:19 david-XPS-13-9350 com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[8849]: [18066:18102:0117/204619:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(367)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -21
jan 17 20:46:20 david-XPS-13-9350 whoopsie[631]: [20:46:20] Could not get the list of active connections: Timeout was reached
jan 17 20:46:22 david-XPS-13-9350 NetworkManager[622]: <info>  (wlp58s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
jan 17 20:46:22 david-XPS-13-9350 dbus[607]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
jan 17 20:46:22 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
jan 17 20:46:22 david-XPS-13-9350 dbus[607]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
jan 17 20:46:22 david-XPS-13-9350 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
jan 17 20:46:22 david-XPS-13-9350 nm-dispatcher[19401]: Dispatching action 'up' for wlp58s0
jan 17 20:46:22 david-XPS-13-9350 gnome-session[9002]: (deja-dup-monitor:10118): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 775 was not found when attempting to remove it
jan 17 20:46:45 david-XPS-13-9350 whoopsie[631]: [20:46:45] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
jan 17 20:46:48 david-XPS-13-9350 com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Applications[8849]: [18066:18102:0117/204648:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(208)] Closing stream with result -101
```